# Can I return a SIP 302 (Redirect) as a response to an incoming call to my Twilio app?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I would like my Twilio app to be able to redirect the inbound SIP INVITE to a different telephony system in some cases. We are not using Twilio's carrier but using our own (thinQ) for origination and termination via SIP.

I do not want to forward the call via the Dial command as it would keep the Twilio app in the loop during call setup.
Is is possible to do this?

Comment: How are you receiving this call? Is it a call to a Twilio number that you are responding to with TwiML? Do you have a SIP trunk or are you using SIP registration?

Comment: It is a call to a ThinQ number which is configured to send the call over SIP to <account_domain>.sip.twilio.com using the instructions provided here - https://www.thinq.com/thinq-voice-origination-with-twilios-bring-your-own-number-byon-service/
No SIP registration is involved.

The idea is for our Twilio app to handle some of these calls but also have the ability to redirect some of them to a different telephony system.

Comment: Thanks for the extra detail. This is beyond what I know about SIP and Twilio, but I'm checking with the team about this and will have an answer for you soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Twilio does not support returning a 302 redirect when receiving SIP as you describe.

When you set up to receive SIP and channel it through Twilio you need to respond to those incoming calls using [TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml) and not SIP commands. Like you suggested, you could use a [`<Dial>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial) which would direct the call elsewhere (including to other SIP addresses if you use [`<Sip>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/sip)) but you cannot just respond with SIP instructions or a redirect.

If you do not want these calls to be handled by Twilio, then you will need to adjust your call routing before the SIP is sent to Twilio.